# How can I visually represent a contingency table with multiple variables as a decision tree in R?

Tags: r, graphics, machine-learning, statistics, survey

For example, say I have a respondent and ask if s/he has a disease. From there I ask if her/his father has had the disease. If yes to the latter question, then I ask if the father is now cured. If the father has not had the disease, then the question is not applicable.

Can I create such a "decision tree" in R or else where?

Here is useable data, where 0 means "no", and 1 means "yes":

```
person_disease <- c(rep(1, 10), rep(0, 20))

father_disease <- c(rep(1, 7), rep(0,18), rep(1,5))

father_cured <- c( rep(0, 4), rep(1,3), rep(NA,18),rep(1,5)  )

##
df <- data.frame(person_disease, father_disease, father_cured)
```

[image]

Comment: perhaps the package partykit (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/partykit/index.html) will help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the data.tree package for that. There are many ways to do what you want. For example:

```
person_disease <- c(rep(1, 10), rep(0, 20))
father_disease <- c(rep(1, 7), rep(0,18), rep(1,5))
father_cured <- c( rep(0, 4), rep(1,3), rep(NA,18),rep(1,5)  )
df <- data.frame(person_disease, father_disease, father_cured)

library(data.tree)

#here, the tree is constructed "manually"
#however, depending on your data and your needs, you might want to generate the tree directly from the data
#many examples for this are available in the vignettes, see browseVignettes("data.tree")
disease <- Node$new("Disease", data = df)
father_disease_yes <- disease$AddChild("Father Disease Yes", label = "Father Disease", edge = "yes", condition = function(df) df[df$person_disease == 1,])
father_cured_yes <- father_disease_yes$AddChild("Father Cured Yes", label = "Father Cured", edge = "yes", condition = function(df) df[df$father_cured == 1,])
father_disease_no <- disease$AddChild("Father Disease No", label = "Father Disease", edge = "no", condition = function(df) df[df$person_disease == 0,])


#data filter (pre-order)
#an alternative would be to do this recursively
disease$Do(function(node) {
  for (child in node$children) {
    child$data <- child$condition(node$data)
  }
})

print(disease, total = function(node) nrow(node$data))


#plotting
#(many more options are available, see ?plot.Node)
SetEdgeStyle(disease,
             fontname = "helvetica",
             arrowhead = "none",
             label = function(node) paste0(node$edge, "\n", "total = ", nrow(node$data)))

SetNodeStyle(disease,
             fontname = "helvetica",
             label = function(node) node$label)

plot(disease)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Indeed there is a package that you can use to create that type of graphic, it is called, conveniently enough, diagram.

It is not an automated graphing process like `barplot()` or `qplot()` but it is something that you can use to make exactly the kind of diagram you are looking to make.

If you are disciplined you could write code to make the process more automatic for your particular data and situation.

The package is called, diagram. and you can find out more about it at this pdf.

[diagram pdf.](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/diagram/vignettes/diagram.pdf)